# Azure AD B2C return url in azure web app plan

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I have a aps.net core mvc app connected to Azure AD B2C ([here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp) is a example I use). When I run the up on my local laptop it runs fine
Return URL: https://localhost:44316/signin-oidc
But when I publish the app to azure web app plan it not works.
With the return URL https:// https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc I become an HTML 404 error when I try to login. With the url: https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/ it goes back to my application without any login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same error when my reply URL in application was http://localhost:port/signin-oidc . I have corrected the app.setting with the callback path to and published :-

```
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
```

And i removed the localhost URL from the reply URL and kept it like below:

[image]

Re started the web app and it worked for me.Try and let know how it worked for you.

Comment: I forgot restart to restart the web app. Thanks now it runs

Comment: Glad to know , it helped.